# Export bar3 plot from Matlab to SVG

Tags: matlab, svg, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm trying to export bar3 plot from matlab to SVG file with to following code:

```
f= figure;
temperatures = [1 2 3 ; 1 2 3];
bar3(temperatures,0.5);
print(f,'-dsvg','radio90.svg');
```

But it failed for that reason:

```
Unknown device 'svg' for hardcopy.
```

I also tried to export the plot with [plot2svg](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401-scalable-vector-graphics--svg--export-of-figures!) but plot2svg isn't support completely in bar3 plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `print`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html), the `-dsvg` flag is for Simulink models only, not MATLAB figures:

[image]

For `plot2svg`, I would report this to the author via the File Exchange.

Comment: OK, I found a way, I can export the file to EPS and then to SVG via external converter.